# Issue separating divs, class affecting other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a noob question, Im going nuts already. So I have a div under another div, they appear to be separated BUT the class from the top div is affecting the div below it. Is there a way of ending a div or something of that sort. Heres what Ive got. The last button in the menu, the contact button, has a class that changes background on hover, which is having the same effect on the    form div below it when I hover the form.

I would be eternally grateful for an answer.

```
<html>
</head>
<style>

/*image scaling*/
.fix{ position:fixed;}
/*text fade into center***************************/

.animated{

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;  
}

.animated3{

 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
 -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
 -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
 animation-fill-mode:both;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
 -moz-animation-duration:1s;
 -ms-animation-duration:1s;
 -o-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-duration:1s;
 -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
  -moz-animation-delay:1s;
 -ms-animation-delay:1s;
  -o-animation-delay:1s;
   animation-delay:1s;   
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes fadeInLeft {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
 }  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 }
 }

 @-moz-keyframes fadeInLeft {
 0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
 }

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
}
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
}

.fadeInLeft {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
-o-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
 }
}

@keyframes fadeOutLeft {
0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-20px);
}
}

 .fadeOutLeft {
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
 -moz-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
 -o-animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
 animation-name: fadeOutLeft;
-webkit-animation-duration:5s;
-moz-animation-duration:5s;
-ms-animation-duration:5s;
-o-animation-duration:5s;
animation-duration:5s;  
 }



 /*initial text on page
 load/////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
.container {position: fixed; top: 25%; left: 10%; z-index:-2; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeinleft {from 
{ transform:translateX(-30px)} to {        
 transform:translate(0px)}} 

.fade-in {
opacity:0; 
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
 animation-duration:1s;}

.fade-in:hover{
 opacity:0; 
 -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
 -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
 animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;

  -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
  -moz-animation-duration:1s;
  animation-duration:1s;

}
.fadeout{
   opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;}
 .fadeout:hover{opacity :0;}


 .box{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 10%;
 float: left;
 background: transparent;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", 
  "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans    Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
  color:grey;
   }
  /*underline*//////////////////////////////////////
  .underlined-example {
 background-color: transparent;
 position:fixed;
}

.underlined-example {
 position: relative;
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 display:inline;

}

.underlined-example:hover {
color: gray;
}

.underlined-example:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;

-webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
-moz-transform: scaleX(0);
-o-transform: scaleX(0);
 transform: scaleX(0);
 }

.underlined-example:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
-moz-transform: scaleX(1);
-o-transform: scaleX(1);
transform: scaleX(1);
}
/*dropdown  
menu.............................................*/

ul#mainNav > li {
float:left;
display:inline;
position:relative;
background-color:transparent;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 32px;
margin-top:-30;
}
.contain{
max-width:1300px;
min-width:1300px;

}
 ul#mainNav > li:hover {
 background:transparent;
 color:gray;
 cursor: pointer;

 }
 ul#mainNav > li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 transition-delay: 0s, 0s;
 } 
 ul#mainNav li ul {
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 height:0;
 padding:15px 0px; 
 margin:0 ;
 min-height: 300px;
 min-width:100px;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 transition-property: opacity, visibility;
 transition-duration: .4s, 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s, .4s;
 line-height: 2;
 }
 ul#mainNav ul li {   
 background-color:transparent;
 }
 ul#mainNav ul li:hover {
 color:gray;
  }
 .bg1:hover:after{
  content:'';
 position: fixed;
 Z-INDEX:-2;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
  background:url(http://
  www.jewelsanddiamonds.com/wp-   
  content/uploads/178482443.jpg) no-repeat   center;
  background-size:cover;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  


}
.bg2:hover:after{
content:'';
Z-INDEX:-2;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://d2aun19a9a38r2.cloudfront.net/
content-  root/engagement/herStyle/ringsToSuitMyFinger.cdo/images
/201601061520/
HS_EngagementGuide_HERSTYLE_WhatRingStyleWillSuitMyFinger.jpg)  
 no-repeat    center;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;   
}
.bg3:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(
http://legacyfinejewelers.com/wp-     
content/uploads/2014/04/jewelry-    background.jpg) 
no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  
}

.bg4:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://images.askmen.com/1080x540/style/watch_snob/
status-    symbol-watches-1107395-TwoByOne.jpg) no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  
}
.bg5:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://www.gia.edu/images
/74357_636x358_1355954767006.jpg)       no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;    
}
.bg6:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://www.diamondjewelers.net/data/solder.jpg) 
no-repeat        center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  
}
.bg7:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://static1.squarespace.com
/static/55bb8a28e4b06ac0de4a4505/t/55cb5a9ae4b00b8482057f1f/1439390362391/) 
no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;    
}
.bg8:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(gif2.gif) no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  
}
.bg9:hover:after{
content:'';
position: fixed;
Z-INDEX:-2;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background:url(http://
legacyfinejewelers.com/wp-    
content/uploads/2014/04/jewelry-
background.jpg) 
no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ;
   -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ;
    -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ;
     -o-animation: fadeInLeft ; 
        animation: fadeInLeft ;
 -webkit-animation-duration:1.3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1.3s;
     -ms-animation-duration:1.3s;
      -o-animation-duration:1.3s;
         animation-duration:1.3s;  
}
/*img size logo/////////////////////////////////////////*/
.logo{
margin-left:38%;
margin-right:40%;
pointer-events:none;
z-index:9999999;
}
/*page load up fades in////////////////////////////////////////////*/
.pageload{ 

-webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
   -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
     -o-animation: fadein 1s; 
        animation: fadein 1s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
from { opacity: 0; }
to   { opacity: 1; }
 /*111111111111111111
 11111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

}

#feedback-page{
text-align:center;
}

#form-main{
width:100%;
float:left;
padding-top:0px;
}

#form-div {
background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
padding-left:35px;
padding-right:35px;
padding-top:35px;
padding-bottom:50px;
width: 450px;
float: left;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left: -260px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}

.feedback-input {
color:#3c3c3c;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:500;
 font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  width:100%;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
 }

.feedback-input:focus{
background: #fff;
box-shadow: 0;
border: 3px solid #3498db;
color: #3498db;
outline: none;
padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused{
color:#30aed6;
border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
}

/* Icons ---------------------------------- */
#name{
background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#name:focus{
background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: 8px 5px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email{
background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#email:focus{
background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#comment{
background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
background-size: 30px 30px;
background-position: 11px 8px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

textarea {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
line-height: 150%;
resize:vertical;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
background-color:white;
}

#button-blue{
font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float:left;
width: 100%;
border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
cursor:pointer;
background-color: #3498db;
color:white;
font-size:24px;
padding-top:22px;
padding-bottom:22px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s;
transition: all 0.3s;
margin-top:-4px;
font-weight:700;
}

#button-blue:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 color: #0493bd;
 }

.submit:hover {
color: #3498db;
}

 .ease {
 width: 0px;
 height: 74px;
 background-color: #fbfbfb;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease;
-moz-transition: .3s ease;
-o-transition: .3s ease;
-ms-transition: .3s ease;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

 .submit:hover .ease{
   width:100%;
   background-color:white;
 }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    #form-div{
    left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    width: 88%;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
 }


 </style>
 <div class="fix pageload">
 <body>
 <div class="logo">
 <img src="logo.png"width="320" >
 </div>
  <div style="z-index:10;" class="contain">
 <ul id="mainNav">
 <li class="bg1 underlined-example" href="">JEWELRY</l>
     <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
 </li> 
 <li href="" class="bg2 underlined-example">ENGAGEMENT</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg3 underlined-example">DIAMONDS</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg4 underlined-example">WATCHES</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg5 underlined-example">CUSTOM CAD</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg6 underlined-example">REPAIR</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg7 underlined-example">APPRAISAL</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li href="" class="bg8 underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
</li>
 <li><a href="/webroot/contact page/contact.html" class="
  bg9 underlined-example">CONTACT </l>
    <ul>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
       <li href="" class="underlined-example">OUR COMPANY</l>
    </ul>        
 </li>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The div above has a class called bg9 which is affecting the div below!

```
  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" 
  type="text"                              
  class="validate
   [required,custom
   [onlyLetter],
   length[0,100]] 
  feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,  
  custom[email]]       feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] 
    feedback-    input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
   </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Please move your code to a plunkr, it is very hard to help you this way since it is very long

Comment: hello sir. just some advice: when posting a question to stack overflow, only give the relevant code. for instance, in your example, you dont need to give your entire code block. the animations and much of your css can be omitted. this way it is easier for people to read your code and give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake youll, forgot to ad an

```
</a>
```

at the end of the link in the menu. Thank you everyone